# Java JSONObject data missing

Tags: java, json

I need to convert string to JSONObject. I found that I have to use something like this `new JSONObject(response.toString());`. But when I get Json from my Philips Hue bridge and convert it to JSONObject, some data missing. I uploaded my code to gitlab https://gitlab.com/JaroslavVond/json/tree/master

As you can see first element ("state") is missing completely (Json after) after converting on line 71 (HueControl.java). But when I print `response.toString()` (line 70) Json format is Ok.

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Comment: The state property is also present in the "after" json file. Read it carefully, until the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the fields are different JSONObject returned by your method. All fields are available in the "Json after" file shared in your Git repo.